# aRest.io - how does it work?

Tags: remote-control, iot, network

With aRest.io you are able control your Arduino/Esp from all over the world - but how?

In the Client SourceCode (found [here](https://github.com/marcoschwartz/aREST/blob/master/aREST.h)) you only find the PubSubClient, which is an MQTT client.

I'm assuming:

My Arduino can (during the aRest.h) subscribe to topics in my aRest.io dashboard (http://dashboard.arest.io/) and if I add something to the dashboard the aRest's Broker will inform my Arduino. But here is my error. How can the Broker contact my Arduino behind the firewall? Does the Arduino use hole punching? Is my attempt wrong?

Comment: The broker doesn't contact the Arduino - the Arduino contacts the broker.

Comment: So the Arduino is polling for commands ?

Comment: Not as such, no. It connects to the broker and sits there waiting for the broker to say something.

Comment: I have to test this tomorrow! Could it be really so easy... Thank you for the hint in the right direction

Comment: check this out ... visual representation of MQTT messages ... https://shiftr.io/shiftr-io/demo

Answer (score 0):

The Client contacts the broker and 
maintain the connection - waitung for topic to be updated.